# Change c# form design without creating an instance of such form

Tags: c#, winforms

So... I have a requirement to build a plugin architecture for an app I am working on, the plugin architecture is actually built using interfaces, and generally works well.

One unique problem I am faced with is allowing a plugin to change the design of a form(s), for argument sake, adding further controls.

The plugin in this example is loaded during an onload event for the main host form.

Now then, can I somehow change any target form in the application and add extra controls without having to create an instance of such form, meaning ui modifications are already done before an instance is created.

I'm thinking searching the application for my target form using reflection and..... This is where I am stumped, how do I change found form, and have the edits available for any new instance?

Comment: Have you taken a look at how WPF/XAML works?  Seems easily doable there (I have no personal experience).

Comment: I have, but that's based on XMl and is indeed easy, though winforms, is a little different.

Comment: So your queston is specific to winforms?

Comment: How about my answer? not useful?

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry i might have been a bit vague, the plugins are to add only small additions to forms already built, let's say for an example to add a button that launches an external service. The developer of these plugins may / may not have the main app, only the interface file, so form inheritance might have been a little overkill, the plugins are responsible for detailing the type of control, the click event handler (if it's a button) so on and so forth. The plugin also details the name of the form as it's target. Jnylen's solution works for me as it allows future forms in main app updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the plugins write to a list of controls that should appear on a given form, then have the form class read from that list when an instance is created.

Comment: I like this idea! If no other suggestions comes forward, I'll accept! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by inheritance.

Assume your form in the plugin is named `pluginForm`. In your application you need to create a form inherited from `pluginForm` instead of `System.Windows.Form`.

The designer will also work. Controls are locked unless you change the modifiers to `Protected`.

Comment: This is a good idea too.  Maybe have the inheritance go the other way around though - have plugins inherit from a form in the main application, and either have the plugin register the inherited form type somehow, or use reflection when you load a plugin to see if it has any types that inherit from the forms that can be overridden.